# Preventing XSS in Node.js / server side javascript

Tags: xss, node.js, serverside-javascript

Any idea how one would go about preventing XSS attacks on a node.js app? Any libs out there that handle removing javascript in hrefs, onclick attributes,etc. from POSTed data?

I don't want to have to write a regex for all that :)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the answers to [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side) suggests borrowing the whitelist-based HTML sanitizer in JS from Google Caja which, as far as I can tell from a quick scroll-through, implements an HTML SAX parser without relying on the browser's DOM.

**Update:** Also, keep in mind that the Caja sanitizer has apparently been given a full, professional security review while regexes are known for being very easy to typo in security-compromising ways.

**Update 2017-09-24:** There is also now [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify). I haven't used it yet, but it looks like it meets or exceeds every point I look for:

- Relies on functionality provided by the runtime environment wherever possible. (Important both for performance and to maximize security by relying on well-tested, mature implementations as much as possible.)

  - Relies on either a browser's DOM or [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) for Node.JS.
- Default configuration designed to strip as little as possible while still guaranteeing removal of javascript.

  - Supports HTML, MathML, and SVG
  - Falls back to Microsoft's proprietary, un-configurable `toStaticHTML` under IE8 and IE9.
- Highly configurable, making it suitable for enforcing limitations on an input which can contain arbitrary HTML, such as a WYSIWYG or Markdown comment field. (In fact, it's the top of the pile here)

  - Supports the usual tag/attribute whitelisting/blacklisting and URL regex whitelisting
  - Has special options to sanitize further for certain common types of HTML template metacharacters.
- They're serious about compatibility and reliability

  - Automated tests running on 16 different browsers as well as three diffferent major versions of Node.JS.
  - To ensure developers and CI hosts are all on the same page, lock files are published.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it basically figured out with regex (yuck) - but I'd love to look into creating a connect middle-ware to sanitize all params.

Answer (score 57):

I've created a module that bundles the Caja HTML Sanitizer

```
npm install sanitizer
```

http://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Using `require('sanitizer').sanitize` strips out all `a[href]` attributes, rather than just naughty ones. For our use case, we need links to still be accepted (just not naughty links, and other xss naughties etc), any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

All usual techniques apply to node.js output as well, which means:

- Blacklists will not work.
- You're not supposed to filter input in order to protect HTML output. It will not work or will work by needlessly malforming the data.
- You're supposed to HTML-escape text in HTML output.

I'm not sure if node.js comes with some built-in for this, but something like that should do the job:

```
function htmlEscape(text) {
   return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').
     replace(/</g, '&lt;').  // it's not neccessary to escape >
     replace(/"/g, '&quot;').
     replace(/'/g, '&#039;');
}
```

Comment: "You're not supposed to filter input" ... "You're supposed to HTML-escape...output": Do you have any reference for this proposed best practice?

Comment: @DanielFlippance these two points are a logical consequence of  "you're supposed to HTML-escape HTML output" and that is the HTML spec.

Comment: Not filtering user input is a risky "best practice". You're opening the door for developer mistakes and in a large project developer mistakes *will* happen, so you'll get hacked over and over again. Keep this in mind if you decide to go this way.

Comment: @LachoTomov For catching developer mistakes I suggest using escaping-by-default template engines. Input mangling has two significant downsides: data loss and false sense of security. For example, people can have apostrophes in their names. You can't filter out everything that could possibly be bad in any context, but if obvious things are filtered out developers may be less vigilant about escaping, and smoke tests may pass when they shouldn't.

Comment: @Kornel sure there are ways to defend against this. But you don't always have control over what other developers use. For ex. if you're building some public API. If it returns unsafe data 50+% of the sites that use it will be hacked. And yeah, you can blame it on the other developers, but that's not the idea - sites are still hacked :) So the right approach depends on the particular use case.

Answer (score 15):

I recently discovered [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) by [chriso](https://github.com/chriso).

### Example

```
get('/', function (req, res) {

  //Sanitize user input
  req.sanitize('textarea').xss(); // No longer supported
  req.sanitize('foo').toBoolean();

});
```

### XSS Function Deprecation

The XSS function is no longer available in this library.

https://github.com/chriso/validator.js#deprecations

Comment: They removed xss support a month ago.

Answer (score 5):

You can also look at [ESAPI](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI). There is a [javascript version of the library](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-js/).  It's pretty sturdy.

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of `validator` module you can use the following script to prevent XSS attack:

```
  var validator = require('validator');

  var escaped_string = validator.escape(someString);
```

Comment: As pointed out in https://nealpoole.com/blog/2013/07/xss-filter-bypass-in-validator-nodejs-module/  --- you cannot simply use the escape filter to prevent XSS. More details are explained in the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet. You should still use the Google Caja Sanitizer.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the npm module `strip-js`. It performs the following actions:

- Sanitizes HTML
- Removes script tags
- Removes attributes such as "onclick", "onerror", etc. which contain JavaScript code
- Removes "href" attributes which contain JavaScript code

https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-js

Comment: Unfortunately I found this library removed valid CSS markup, like `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2021-04-16**: xss is a module used to filter input from users to prevent XSS attacks.

Sanitize untrusted HTML (to prevent XSS) with a configuration specified by a Whitelist.

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss
Project Homepage: http://jsxss.com

Answer (score 0):

You should try library npm "insane".
https://github.com/bevacqua/insane

I try in production, it works well. Size is very small (around ~3kb gzipped).

- Sanitize html
- Remove all attributes or tags who evaluate js
- You can allow attributes or tags that you don't want sanitize

The documentation is very easy to read and understand.
https://github.com/bevacqua/insane

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still watching this.
It seems like the [xss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss) package to be popular and maintained

From the docs:

```
var xss = require("xss");
var html = xss('<script>alert("xss");</script>');
console.log(html);
```