# Display a string with \n in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I need to display a string containing `\n` using Jade and I want to convert those characters in `<br>`. I tried to do that in two ways:

```
- var s = 'text\nand\ntext';
p= string
p= string.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
```

But in the first case I can't see spaces and with the second paragraph the HTML is escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it liked this:

```
- var text = '<script></script>\nhi';
p!= text.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
```

It doesn't escape html special characters but since I'm using `<meta charset="utf-8">` it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is the text supplied by a user?  If so, you may need to worry about [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).  User input should always be escaped.  Otherwise they could do something malicious like inputting `<script>window.location = 'myevilsite.com'</script>`.  Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3705356/1181886) that should get you started.  If the text is safe, then disregard the above :)

Answer (score 2):

use `!=` instead of `=`

```
p!= string.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
```

see the [docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#code) for more infos

Comment: but in that way if `string` contains, for instance, a `<script>` tag it'll be rendered

Comment: isn't that what you want? you can also use - var html = "<script></script>"
| !{html}

Comment: I want to convert \n in <br> but the `html` var in your example should be rendered as `&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
    p
      striped = body.replace(/\r/g, '')
      paragraph = body.split(/\n{2,}/g)
      if paragraph.length
        each para in paragraph
          | <p>
          line = para.split(/\n/g)
          first = line.shift()
          | #{first}
          each li in line
            | <br />
            | #{li}
          | </p>
```

I throw away `\r`'s and split on 2 or more `\n`'s. If that results in a non-empty array, I loop the array and add a beginning `<p>` tag. Any lines with a single `\n` are split and looped with `<br>` tags, then it ends with a `</p>` tag. Lather, rinse, repeat. Bonus: strings are rendered properly escaped.

Jade is awesome! (as is regex)