# Will this be enough to prevent xss on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xss

I have a small website with few users, lately i've been digging into website security and stumbled across xss attacks. I found a loophole where in my code through self testing where i could create a username as `<b>username</b>` and it would appear in bold. Now, any action taken by the user is sent to my server for validation, I've explicitly banned "`<`" & "`>`" chars. Will this be enough to prevent xss attacks?

Also, my text fields are very limited (10 letters), though, i guess this can be bypassed by calling the function in chrome dev tools?

Will this do or is there anything else i should be aware of? Note that this site contains no important data to be stolen or hacked, i just want it fully protected as xss attacks can be quite nasty and redirect users and what not, ultmiately i feel responsible that my site works the intended way..

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: javascript (node js)

Comment: sanitize all user data you ingest, but also sanitize it when you generate your pages. `<b>username</b>` might be a dumb username, but as user generated content you _need_ to do santizing not just when you ingest (e.g. accept via POST) but also when you turn it back into page data: make your server perform HTML entity replacement, and always use `textContent` in the browser, never use `innerHTML`.

Comment: yeah i added this 'code' function htmlEscape(text) {
   return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').
     replace(/</g, '&lt;').  // it's not neccessary to escape >
     replace(/"/g, '&quot;').
     replace(/'/g, '&#039;');
}'code'

Answer (score 2):

Use frameworks  .Do not try to make the wheel again! A LOT of people have spent lots of hours to prevent XSS and more in the largest frameworks.

[Preventing XSS in Node.js / server side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705356/preventing-xss-in-node-js-server-side-javascript)

Comment: np :) If it solve the problem. Please set my answer as answered