# How do I make an editable DIV look like a text field?

Tags: html, css

I've got a `DIV` which has `contentEditable=true` so the user can edit it.  The problem is that it doesn't look like a text field, so it may not be clear to the user that it can be edited.

Is there a way that I can style the `DIV` so that it appears to the user like a text input field?

Comment: background: white; border: 1px solid #666; cursor: text; ? :P see [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZevvE/)

Comment: I suppose make it look like a `textarea`? http://jsfiddle.net/vwPgT/

Comment: @mkk - Might help a *little* if you added some sample text: http://jsfiddle.net/ZevvE/1/

Comment: @Jared :) good job! ;-) now it is much harder to confuse it with div.. oh it is a div, i forgot :)

Comment: @mkk - I *personally* think my demo is clearer, but hey, it is what it is.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

These look the same as their real counterparts in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. They degrade gracefully and look OK in Opera and IE9, too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AbKTQ/

CSS:

```css
textarea {
    height: 28px;
    width: 400px;
}

#textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

input {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 400px;
}

#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

HTML:

```html
<textarea>I am a textarea</textarea>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>I look like textarea</div>

<input value="I am an input" />
<div id="input" contenteditable>I look like an input</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What exactly does _-webkit-small-control_ and _medium -moz-fixed_ do? They seem to make the font look monospaced in Firefox v13.0

Comment: @Hengjie Those are the default styles that the browsers use when displaying input fields.

Comment: to make this work proper in IE9 add another div inside textarea div.like this.<div id="textarea" contenteditable><div>I look like textarea</div></div>

Comment: here is an usecase, try do a copy paste html contents in them.  You will see the difference.

Comment: Is it possible to get the cursor position from the text-area lookalike?

Comment: Should also add - background:white;

Comment: What if I want another div inside this div, which I don't want it to be editable?

Comment: I can not find any information about `-webkit-small-control`. Who can give me some information?

Comment: It's not the same. The div can accept formating, like bold, etc.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the design has also changed slightly over the years. At least for the input field. The corners look rounded.

Comment: Perfect one. I found one missing feature, that is in textarea when it reaches the border it breaks word into new line, but not with the above solution. Any one looking for that? use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 25):

If you use bootstrap just add `form-control` class. For example:

```
class="form-control"
```

Comment: This is a great answer and I feel is the cleanest.  My vote is for this to be the right answer.

Comment: Any way to allow the user to expand the area? Normal textarea does this.

Answer (score 15):

In WebKit, you can do: `-webkit-appearance: textarea;`

Comment: Well, that's just too convenient.

Answer (score 3):

You could go for an inner box shadow:

```
div[contenteditable=true] {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #666;
}
```

I updated the jsfiddle from Jarish: http://jsfiddle.net/ZevvE/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this for matching Chrome's style, extended from Jarish's example. Notice the cursor property which previous answers have omitted.

```
cursor: text;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
font: medium -moz-fixed;
font: -webkit-small-control;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 2px;
resize: both;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all these is they don't address if the lines of text are long and much wider that the div   overflow:auto does not ad a scroll bar that works right.  Here is the perfect solution I found:

Create two divs. An inner div that is wide enough to handle the widest line of text and then a smaller outer one which acts at the holder for the inner div:

```
<div style="border:2px inset #AAA;cursor:text;height:120px;overflow:auto;width:500px;">
    <div style="width:800px;">

     now really long text like this can be put in the text area and it will really <br/>
     look and act more like a real text area bla bla bla <br/>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a TEXTAREA of similar size under your DIV, so the standard control's frame would be visible around div.

It's probably good to set it to be disabled, to prevent accidental focus stealing.

Comment: Yeah, not sure this is what the OP is looking for in the answer.

Comment: If you want the textfield to scale automatically with the contents of the div this is getting hard.