# how to display html text inside the textarea control in asp.net[.net 4 framework]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, asp.net-controls

I have added one submit button and one textArea control in asp.net(4 framework) page.Whenever user clicks submit button, then i will get some html text and needs to display it in the textArea control.

for example: 
(i) `<B><I>some text</I></B>` then i have to display the text with **BOLD** and *ITALIC* style in the textArea contol

(ii) Also, needs to display Html TABLE inside the textArea control.

I dont know is this possible or not...

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: what about Html encoding and decoding ?

Comment: @Jodha:Can you explain more about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use literal control for this requirement.

```
  <asp:Literal id="literal1" Text="I love ASP!" runat="server" />
```

In C#,

```
   literal1.text=htmlString;
```

It is working good for me...

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the standard textarea.

You will need a rich text edit box. There are lot of editors available for this.

Take a look at

[Tiny MCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

or

jQuery based [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)

Answer (score 0):

Textbox used in general are limited in their functionality so in order to get additional editing and features, you must go through the functionality of Richtextbox.
I think this link might help:
[Richtextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot display a table inside TextArea but you can surely set it's css to display text in bold & italics.

You can use textarea{
font-weight: bold;
font-style:italic;
}

You can use TinyMCE as mentioned by nunespascal, alternatively you can use div to look like a textarea, please check the below link.

[How do I make an editable DIV look like a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field)