# Adding the content of a <div> to a textbox on click of a Button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

First I have created a `<div>....</div>` which is hidden on pageload using javascript function. Then I have created an empty textbox using forms. Now when anyone clicks a button then the whole content of the hidden `<div>....</div>` should be loaded in the textbox in the form. What should be code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this way

```
<div id="hiddendiv"><strong>some</strong> content</div>
<button onclick="copyfunction();">click me</button>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<script>
    function copyfunction() {
        var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
        var hiddendiv = document.getElementById('hiddendiv');
        textarea.value = hiddendiv.innerText;
    }
</script>
```

tested, it works

Comment: @bukfixart yeah no doubt it works, but the problem with this code is that it shows HTML syntax of the content in <div> into the textbox but i want to display the composed form of it, i mean the outcome of the HTML code used and not the code itself

Comment: ok, just edited the post, now it uses `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: @bukfixart thank u very much!!...may i give you a little more trouble?
can you edit the code such that the textbox is also able to display any css styling done to the <div>. I mean this code displays only the whole text but no effects. Thanks a lot once again.!

Comment: sorry, this isn't possible with normal textareas. here you need `contendeditable` elements, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textbox_id").val($("#div_id").html());
```