# Mimicng caret in a textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, richtextbox, caret

I am trying to mimic the caret of a textarea for the purpose of creating a very light-weight rich-textarea. I don't want to use something like codemirror or any other massive library because I will not use any of their features.

I have a `<pre>` positioned behind a textarea with a transparent background so i can simulate a highlighting effect in the text. However, I also want to be able to change the font color (so its not always the same). So I tried `color: transparent` on the textarea which allows me to style the text in any way I want because it only appears on the `<pre>` element behind the textarea, but the caret disappears.

I have gotten it to work fairly well, although it is not perfect. The main problem is that when you hold down a key and spam that character, the caret seems to always lag one character behind. Not only that, it seems to be quite resource heavy..

If you see any other things in the code that need improvement, feel free to comment on that too!

Here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/2t5pu/25/

And for you who don't want to visit jsfiddle for whatever reason, here's the entire code:

CSS:

```
textarea, #fake_area {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font: 16px "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    resize: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-word;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#fake_area {
    /* hide */
    opacity: 0;
}
#caret {
    width: 1px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f00;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fake_area"><span></span></div>
<div id="caret"></div>
<textarea id="textarea">test</textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var fake_area = document.getElementById("fake_area").firstChild;
var fake_caret = document.getElementById("caret");
var real_area = document.getElementById("textarea");

$("#textarea").on("input keydown keyup propertychange click", function () {
    // Fill the clone with textarea content from start to the position of the caret. 
    // The replace /\n$/ is necessary to get position when cursor is at the beginning of empty new line.
doStuff();    
});

var timeout;
function doStuff() {
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(function() {
        fake_area.innerHTML = real_area.value.substring(0, getCaretPosition(real_area)).replace(/\n$/, '\n\u0001');
    setCaretXY(fake_area, real_area, fake_caret, getPos("textarea"));
    }, 10);
}


    function getCaretPosition(el) {
        if (el.selectionStart) return el.selectionStart;
        else if (document.selection) {
            //el.focus();
            var r = document.selection.createRange();
            if (r == null) return 0;

            var re = el.createTextRange(), rc = re.duplicate();
            re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
            rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

            return rc.text.length;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function setCaretXY(elem, real_element, caret, offset) {
        var rects = elem.getClientRects();
        var lastRect = rects[rects.length - 1];

        var x = lastRect.left + lastRect.width - offset[0] + document.body.scrollLeft,
            y = lastRect.top - real_element.scrollTop - offset[1] + document.body.scrollTop;

        caret.style.cssText = "top: " + y + "px; left: " + x + "px";
        //console.log(x, y, offset);
    }

    function getPos(e) {
        e = document.getElementById(e);
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        while (e.offsetParent !== null){
            x += e.offsetLeft;
            y += e.offsetTop;
            e = e.offsetParent;
        }
        return [x, y];
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your caret is lagging due to real caret apearing for a little repiod of time. Try to enter few lines of text and then click and hold left mouse button on different row and you'll see it. To overcome this you'll have to set opacity of text area to 0. But then you'll have to deal with correctly displaying text.

Comment: do you really need to update the cursor 100 times a second? i would think 5 or 10 would suffice. it's why your app is running slow...

Comment: @dandavis: needs to be as responsive as the default one.

Comment: @Lindrian: it won't be as responsive if the CPU is flooded. there really is no need to poll at all, you can use mouse, paste, and keyboard events to position the cursor accurately and instantly without polling.

Comment: @dandavis: I have tried and failed, thus this bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't an editable Div element solve the entire problem?

Code that does the highlighting:

http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/XYGgz/3/

```
var prevText = "";
var isHighlighting = false;
$("#textarea").bind("paste drop keypress input textInput DOMNodeInserted", function (e){
    if (!isHighlighting)
    {
        var currentText = $(this).text();
        if (currentText != prevText)
        {
            doSave();
            isHighlighting = true;
            $(this).html(currentText
                   .replace(/\bcolored\b/g, "<font color=\"red\">colored</font>")
                   .replace(/\bhighlighting\b/g, "<span style=\"background-color: yellow\">highlighting</span>"));
            isHighlighting = false;
            prevText = currentText;
            doRestore();
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this made some editing functions to be lost, like <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>... and when pasting text, the caret stays at the beginning of the pasted text.

I have combined code from other answers to produce this code, so please, give them credit.

- [How do I make an editable DIV look like a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field)
- [Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container)

**EDIT:** I have discovered something interesting... the native caret appears if you use a contentEditable element, and inside of it you use another element with the invisible font:

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable style="color: red"><div style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent;">This is some hidden text.</div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/qsRdg/4/

Comment: The entire goal was to allow me to do simple syntax highlighting. I tried doing this with a contenteditable div, but the caret would jump around, get reset, etc. Just was not reliable.

Comment: @Lindrian Take a look at the EDIT, you may find it interesting... unfortunately the caret with transparent text worked only in chrome and IE, not in firefox. =)

Answer (score 2):

The lag is I think due to the keyup triggering the doStuff a bit too late, but the keydown is a bit too soon.

Try this instead of the jQuery event hookup (normally I'd prefer events to polling, but in this case it might give a better feel)...

```
setInterval(function () { doStuff(); }, 10); // 100 checks per second

function doStuff() {
    var newHTML = real_area.value.substring(0, getCaretPosition(real_area)).replace(/\n$/, '\n\u0001');
    if (fake_area.innerHTML != newHTML) {
        fake_area.innerHTML = newHTML;
        setCaretXY(fake_area, real_area, fake_caret,                         getPos("textarea"));
    }
}
```

...or here for the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2t5pu/27/

Comment: I'm sorry but this isnt really much better than what I had before unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work great and doesn't use any polls, just like i was talking about in the comments.

```
var timer=0;
$("#textarea").on("input keydown keyup propertychange click paste cut copy mousedown mouseup change", function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer=setTimeout(update, 10);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2t5pu/29/

maybe i'm missing something, but i think this is pretty solid, and it behaves better than using intervals to create your own events.

EDIT:  added a timer to prevent que stacking.

Comment: Hold down a key, it still lags behind. I don't think my solution is worth working on any further.

Comment: well, it's super smooth for me. i updated the answer to deal with lag on older machines. if the machine is really old, even textareas can get slightly behind...