# Why the first letter of the `textarea` and `input` elements are not red?

Tags: html, css

Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (x64), Firefox 53.0.2 (x64), Linux

Why the first letter of the `textarea` element is not red?

The `textarea::first-line` works fine (in my Google Chrome, but not in Firefox) but the `textarea::first-letter` doesn' work in my example. I have the similar behaviour for an `input` element too.

I haven't problems with both cases if I use `p` instead of `textarea` or `input`.

```css
input::first-line,
textarea::first-line {
  color: green;
}

input::first-letter,
textarea::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols='40' rows='4'>Sfrrr sdfsdfsd dsf ddsfds fds fdsfds fsdfds fsdfdsf sd fdss d dsf ssdfddfsddsfdssdsf ss dfsds sdf sdf sdfs fsf sf sdfsdfsdfs df sdffsdf sf sdf sdf sf sf sdf sdf sdf sdf sf sdf sdf sf sdf sdf sdf sfsdfsdf sdf sdf sdfs sdf sdfds dsf sdf sdf sdfsdf sdf dsfs</textarea>
<input value='Sfrrr sdfsdfsd dsf ddsfds fds fdsfds fsdfds' />
```

Comment: Works fine on Edge on Windows 10, but not Chrome.

Comment: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-first-letter) already refers to [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6185). This must answer your question.

Comment: @Al.G. I'm not sure it does. That bug says that the first character is not selectable (i.e., selecting all of the text in the textarea doesn't select the first character). This is saying the first character's style is not applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first letter of input value and change it's color via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397450/select-first-letter-of-input-value-and-change-its-color-via-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the *::first-letter* pseudo-element to work you need to set your element's display property to block and use a block level container:

In CSS, the *::first-letter* pseudo-element applies to block-like containers such as block, list-item, table-cell, table-caption, and inline-block elements.

The *::first-letter* pseudo-element can be used with all such elements that contain text, or that have a descendant in the same flow that contains text.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter

```css
textarea, input {
  display: block;
}

input::first-line,
textarea::first-line {
  color: green;
}

p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><textarea cols='40' rows='4'>Sfrrr sdfsdfsd dsf ddsfds fds fdsfds fsdfds fsdfdsf sd fdss d dsf ssdfddfsddsfdssdsf ss dfsds sdf sdf sdfs fsf sf sdfsdfsdfs df sdffsdf sf sdf sdf sf sf sdf sdf sdf sdf sf sdf sdf sf sdf sdf sdf sfsdfsdf sdf sdf sdfs sdf sdfds dsf sdf sdf sdfsdf sdf dsfs</textarea></p>
<p><input value='Sfrrr sdfsdfsd dsf ddsfds fds fdsfds fsdfds' /></p>
```