# Unique CSS styles for "+" and "-" when user types in input

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user types in `+` in my `input`, I would like the `+` to be green

Ex: +10000 --> "+" should be green and 10000 should be black

When the user types in `-` in my `input`, I would like the `-` to be red

Ex: -10000 --> "-" should be red and 10000 should be black

My idea was to use `::first-letter`, but I realize it doesn't work on `input`

Is this possible at all with css and javascript? Do I need some fancy Regex to accomplish this?

```css
input {
  font-size: 100px;
}

/* only - should be red */
input::first-letter {
  color: red;
}

/* only + should be green */
input::first-letter {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks can't from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397450/select-first-letter-of-input-value-and-change-its-color-via-css)

Comment: @pilchard But even if I recognize the first letter of the input using `keyup` how would I just select that character to change the color when it's all one clump of html in my input?

Comment: Does this answer can solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397496/6670191

Comment: I think that you can't implement that function when you use the 'input' tag. If you want to it then maybe you should use another method (ex: contenteditable div)

Comment: You can't do this in a standard input element. You would need to use a replaced element, perhaps a content editable div that updates a hidden field for the actual value. You would alos need to wrap your styled elements in a span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `<input>` element with `.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`, then you can attach an event listener on `keyup`. From here, you can use `.style.color` to update the color based on `.value[0]`:

```js
const target = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
target.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value[0] === '-') {
    this.style.color = 'red';
  }
  else if (this.value[0] === '+') {
    this.style.color = 'green';
  }
  else {
    this.style.color = 'black';
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" />
</body>

</html>
```

Note that the above snippet only checks the *first* character inputted. If you want to check for *any* occurrence of the target character, you can loop over the `.value`.

Comment: Is there a way to not make the whole text change color but only "+" and "-" ?

Ex +10000 --> only + is green, 10000 does not change color
Ex -10000 --> only - is red, 10000 does not change color

Comment: It will change the whole word color.

Comment: So no way to separate colors of different text characters in the same input?

Comment: In order to change only the color of the first character, the corresponding element must be regarded as an HTML element, so I don't think it can be done with a value of input tag

Comment: Silverstar is correct; I'm fairly certain that the only way to achieve setting *only* the first character would be to have it as a separate HTML element. It's possible to trigger `::first-letter` through JavaScript, but again, it doesn't apply to `<input>`.

Comment: You can avoid the lag by listening to `input` instead of `keyup`

Comment: as @Silverstar and Obsidian Age has stated, a perfect solution to this question is impossible because I would need a separate HTML element. I will select this as the answer because it seems to be the closest possible solution to this question.