# Why make a div look like a textarea and not use a regular textarea?

Tags: html

I was looking around GMail and just found that the Message Composition uses:

- textarea for recipients
- input for subject
- div for the message

I want to focus on the **div for the message** part. So I did some research and found out to be able to make a **`div`** behave like a **`textarea`** simply do [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field).

But my question is. Why do it? Why not just use an ordinary textarea? Does it provide any additional security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they cover it with JavaScript to make it a ~WYSIWYG control instead of a plain text one.

Comment: I see. . so its just for easy styling of the content. That's understandable, thanks!