# Protect part of input text box in the contact form

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I was wondering whether it is possible to edit the code of Contact Us form in blogger so that 
i can put a predefined text in the message box of the contact form ,

This predefined text should be not be editable by the user and he can still write his message in the message box , which actually will get appended to the predefined message.

I have seen many persons with customized contact us form for Blogger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if I correctly understood your problem. To my understanding, I feel your problem can be achieved in two ways.

1. Position Div and using padding left to your input field

> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>       <div style="position:absolute;">
>           This is non editable
>       </div>
>       <div>
>           <input id="messagebox" size="90" style="padding-left:115px;"> 
>       </div>
>   <body>
> <html>
> ```

2.
 Using readonly input tag

> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>       <div>
>           <input type="text" value="This is non editable" readonly size="16">
>           <input id="messagebox" size="90" style="margin-left:-5px; border-left: 0px"> 
>       </div>
>   <body>
> <html>
> ```

Comment: Most Welcome, please remember to accept the answer, if it worked for you and hopefully it will be helpful for other users too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use textarea with attribute readonly. Like this:

```
<textarea readonly>
    Here is some readonly text
</textarea>
```

You can achieve this with simple div element of HTML. Like this

```
<div>
    Here is some readonly text
</div>
```

To use "div" as "textarea" you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field).