# How to make input field to show real time markups

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I want to know how to make a **input text** field like the one in *facebook* or *twitter* where **text smiles are converted into graphics and the ability to add extra markup**.

I have gone through other stackoverflow questions like 
[How do I make an editable DIV look like a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field)

So I know how to make an **editable div using `contenteditable`**, thats not what I wanted to know.

I have inspected facebook comment box via chrome and it shows they use an Invisible `input` box and a `div` to show the output

[image: I have removed facebook classes and added some my own styles to see the input box]

> I have removed facebook classes and added some my own styles to see the input box

So what i want to know is

1. How the `input` can be **hidden** and the things that user enters shows up in the `div`
2. How to make the hidden `input` field to be selected when the user focus on `div`
3. I want to know how to implement this technique with an `input[type=text]` and `div`

In General It would be much helpful if adding a hash tag method is explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keypress event of jQuery for input and you can update any div or hidden input element

```js
$( "#target" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(".div").html($(this).val());// you can play with this
  $(".input").val($(this).val());
});
```

For more details visit jquery doc page http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

For css tell me in details what you want to do i will explain it

With Javascript:

```js
//Add this on input
onKeyDown="keyCounter(this,'div id')" 


function keyCounter(field,cntfield) {
 var fval=field.value;
 //this is the div you can play around
 document.getElementById('cntfield').innerHTML  = fval;
 
}
```

Comment: I am interested in reverse engineering  Facebook comment box!

Comment: Any idea how they convert text smiles to graphics and makes hash tags. And i want raw javascript

Comment: you did not want to use jQuery?

Comment: whit jquery you can convert a text smiley to graphics visit this url: http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/   if you dont want to use jquery do let me know i will try to help you

Comment: i have added a JavaScript for keydown check this if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I could do this by,

> - Hiding the input using
> - Add CSS to make the div look like input field (`.falseInput` )
> - When user selects the *falseInnput* the hidden Input is focused
> - The JavaScript function is fired when *keyup* event is used

### HTML

```
<body>
  <input id="Input" type="text" name="Input" />
  <div class="falseInput"></div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
   /*to hide the input field use Opacity, if 
    display:none
    is used the input cannot be focused*/

    input{opacity: 0; } 

    .falseInput{ 
       //css to make div look like input feild
      // by modifying the :focus also changing styles
    }
```

### JavaScript

```
//This example is used inorder to add extra markup for makinng a hashtags

  document.getElementById("Input").addEventListner("keyup", process, false);
  document.querySelector(".falseInput").addEventListner("click", function(e){
     document.getElementById("Input").focus();
   }, false);

  function process(e){
   //for processing hashtags
     var tag = { hash: 51, space:32 }
      , hashtags = false
      ,input_feild = document.querySelector(".falseInput");

     switch (e.which) {
        case tag.hashtag:

            if(e.shiftKey === true && e.keyCode == tag.hash){
                 input_field.appendChild(this.value + "<span class='highlight'>");
            }
            hashtags = true;
            break;
        case tag.space:
            if(hashtags) {
                input_field.appendChild(this.value + "</span>");
                hashtags = false;
            }
            break;
    }   

  }
```