# why the border not set on input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I try to add border on my input field .I am able to add the border on text field but it apply on whole portion .I need to add border to only the input field till where character start scrolling.In other word if you start typing on input field after few characters it start scrolling horizontally I need to add border up to that , not to whole width of input .

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXvKeb

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">

    <h1 class="title">Station ID</h1>


</ion-header-bar>


<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">StationName</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" class="bdr">
        </label>
        </div>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Footer!</h1>
</ion-footer-bar>








  </body>
</html>
```

I added class **"bdr"**

Comment: Where is your bdr class? and where you call the style sheet?

Comment: please check my code  I add that class on css  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXvKeb

Comment: You can't input field like you expect. But you can write custom code to achieve what you expect

Comment: can we make custom input field in ionic ?

Comment: You can make elements other than an `input` editable, and add custom styling/behavior to your liking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field

Comment: You need to do like what Dpeif said :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using `ng-class` and `ng-change`.

your text field should be

Add some code in your controller

```
     $scope.customClassName=undefined;
     $scope.changeBorder=function(){
       $scope.customClassName=undefined;
       if(user.username.length>1){
       $scope.customClassName="bdr";
      }    
}
```

If you write any values in your input field, then the function will execute and check the condition, finally update the `ng-class` to your original class :)