# set font-face/font-family using setAttribute (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, font-face

I am creating and styling a `div` using javascript like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute('style',  'box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px #888888; \
                            background-color: #ffb734; \
                            etc...
                           ');
```

I have to do it this way as I am inserting the `div` from a chrome extension content script.

How can I change the font face, if I have downloaded a font `myFont.ttf` to the same directory?

Here is what I've tried:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute('style',  'box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px #888888; \
                            background-color: #ffb734; \
                            @font-face {\
                                font-family: '" + 'openSans' + "'; \
                                src: url('" + 'OpenSans-Semibold.ttf' + "') \
                            } \
                           ');
```

But this breaks the `div` (it stops showing up)

Thanks in advance!

p.s. Is it a better approach to instead make a css file and include it in my manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents of a CSS declaration block (excluding the delimiting braces).](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax)

That means that [at-rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#at-rule) are not allowed in that context.

Comment: Thanks, so is there an alternative method for this context?

Comment: @NoamHacker you can use the `font` or `font-family` properties, that's it. If you are limited to javascript solutions, you should probably check the [FontFaceSet interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a dynamic text box the user can change? If so this answer will guide you through creating one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8957518/5914723

If not, then here is some JS that will modify a div. You're modifying the HTML DOM with this code, HTML and CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/ohodgo7u/

HTML: empty div

```
<div id="changeMe"></div>
```

JS

```
var changeMe = document.getElementById("changeMe");
changeMe.innerHTML = "You can style me too!";
document.getElementById("changeMe").style.font = "bold 40px serif";
```

Answer (score 0):

font-face should be specified in an external css file, yes, it's a better approach to make a css file and include it in your manifest.

BTW, use `+` rather than `\` to break the string in multi lines. The latter is [not preferred](https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings#comments).