# Align text inside input properly

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input type text (also tried with textarea), and I've set its height to like 400px, because I want to make it like a text box. For example like that one that i'm typing in right now. Where the text will wrap on new line and so on. THe problem is that the text only goes in the center and scrolls to the right, instead of wrapping. How do I do it properly?

EDIT: Well i've described it, but if here is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="contact_message" pattern=".{10,}">
```

CSS:

```
#contact_message {
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: post your code here or on any online editor like jsfiddle or codepen and share its link here

Comment: Textarea is the one you need to use. not input type text.

in text area you can use rows attribute for multiline.

Comment: use `textarea` instead of `text` type `input`

Comment: I'm curious now; you said you already tried a textarea, so how did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here: a `<textarea>` and a `<div contenteditable>`. I would recommend using a `<textarea>`.

```css
textarea {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<textarea minlength="10">this is some really long text that should break into new lines whenever this crosses 400 pixels wide and go to the new line ehahoitheiahithahihhoghaohhtoihaoiehhnbieoaihtoai</textarea>
```

You can use a `div` with `contenteditable`:

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  
  }
```

```html
<div contenteditable>some really long text that should span more than one line when this crosses 400pixels and go into a new line iaoheotheaothoehtoihieothaoihtihiaohtieathioehwaoteahtioehahthahaiohh</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextArea not input tag.

and textarea will do the needful by default.
also there is one option for multiline like setting attribute rows.

and then you will not need to set height.

check fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/yxbpoh2d/

```
<textarea name="message" id="contact_message"></textarea>
#contact_message {
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the comma. You can also use `minlength` property.

Comment: what comma? that is users question.

Comment: Yes, but you can correct mistakes in the user's code.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options that you can use.Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AbKTQ/) is a fiddle.

```
 textarea {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#contact_message {
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="contact_message" rows="4" cols="50">

</textarea>
```