# Select textarea value while text area is updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area. The value of this text area is to keep updating using a loop.
What I want is to select any portion of the text area and copy the selected text. But I cannot select the text since the textarea is keep updating.
Please see the sample code below.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var x = 0;
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#txtData').append('Test value ' + x++ + '\n');
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <textarea id="txtData" style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow: auto;"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

As in the above image. I want to select the text.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: I can select in Chrome

Comment: I just copied from the above running snippet and pasted in notepad it pasted me the selected text in notepad.... or can you elaborate the question?

Comment: I just updated time out to 100ms, when the content is updating rapidly, unable to select any portion, once it selected it goes away.

Comment: @mplungjan, in firefox its not working.

Comment: This might be a FF-specific thing that you will need to work around.  For example, is there a particular reason why you're using a textarea?  If it doesn't need to be, you can style a div like a textarea (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8957518), change your append to $('#txtData').append('Test value ' + x++ + '<br>') and that should give you the same look but you'll be able to select while the loop keeps appending.

Comment: @Doug F, I tried that already and with the <div> solution this works perfectly. But in my project there are large number of data are writing to the textarea. with the <div> solution, when the data count becomes more, its getting stuck.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.  Have you tried using a multiselect dropdown menu?  You would need to change your append to $('#txtData').append('<option value="Test value ' + x++ + '">Test value ' + x++ + '</option>'); but I just tested it out in Firefox and I have no problem selecting while the dropdown menu is populating, though I can't say for sure if you would have the same performance issues or not as you did when you tried earlier with the div.