# JavaScript: make html text plain text

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've got a js-function which takes string as a parameter and get it displayed in a div element. Such string may contain html tags.

How do I force JS display inner text in div-elements as html-text with html-tags. And, also, what is an adequate way to filter particular tags, i.e. apply certain tags for styling and just print others.

Comment: I fear this question will once again awaken zalgo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to replace `&` and `<` (and optionally `>` if you like, but you don't have to) with their respective entities, using `String#replace` ([spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.11), [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) for instance.

Comment: Thank's a lot. Yeah, I just encode "<" with its code except those "<" which follow cetain tags. I think that in my case it is sufficient to avoid any XSS attacks.

Comment: @user1041195 do not forget that **any** tag can have embedded even handler with JavaScript and "javascript:" is a valid prefix for URLs. If your users may insert HTML do not handmade this.

Comment: @user1041195: Seconding what Adriano said: If you're going to allow some HTML tags, your best bet is to use an XSS library rather than doing this yourself. If you do it yourself, do a whitelist of tags (disallowing anything else) and for each tag, a whitelist of the attributes you allow on that tag and (in some cases) the form those attributes are allowed to take. You wouldn't want to allow `<strong onclick="doSomethingReallyEvil();">Look, bunnies!</strong>` or similar.

Comment: Yes, attributes are also to be considered. Adriano, T.J. Crowder, thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I think it's too easy to forget something about HTML (specially if this is his _first_ time) but you've got my +1 for the straightforward explanation of what he should do!

Answer (score 1):

> And, also, what is an adequate way to filter particular tags, i.e. apply certain tags for styling and just print others.

To put directly user inserted HTML code is **dangerous** for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You should use some tool to sanitize HTML code (here on StackOverflow, for example, you can use some HTML tags).

As posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side) here on SO you can use this client-side sanitizer:  http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/html-sanitizer.js
On the other hand you may need to do this on the server-side, which one depends on your environment (ASP.NET? PHP?).