# Prevent XSS flaws

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)

I am working on a HTML5 and JQuery website that parse data from JSON files.

I have a doubt on how to prevent Prevent XSS flaws for this project and what I should do to optimize the HTML5 and Javascript to don´t have any issue with XSS.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSS is a flaw that occurs only on sites that dynamically generate pages. Web sites with Static pages are not vulnerable to XSS.

XSS flaws are of three types.

- Persistent - User input consists of malicious software code that gets stored in the web application, and gets rendered thereafter in every request to read that along with piece of data.
- Non-Persistent - User input consists of malicious code that get returned in server's response to the request, it doesn't get stored in the web app so it is specific to that request.
- DOM-based - This does not involve web server, it is local to the web browser. I think this is what you are looking for.

Check out [this](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246920/Cross%20Site%20Scripting) link for good explanation on XSS. To avoid XSS you must perform input validations.