# Parsing HTML (from string) in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I wrote this cross-browser code for parsing XML from a string:

```
var xparse = function (xml$s) {
    var xml, p;
    if (typeof(DOMParser) !== 'undefined') {
        var p = new DOMParser();
        xml = p.parseFromString(xml$s, 'text/xml');
    } else {
        xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        xml.async = 'false';
        xml.loadXML(xml$s);
    }

    return xml;
};
```

It works just fine for XML, but I've been trying to adapt it to parse HTML. For any browser but IE, it's as simple as changing `text/xml` to `text/html`. I can't seem to find any information on an HTML equivalent of `ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')` though. I'd also like to avoid using any frameworks.

Comment: What's the purpose? To inject it into the DOM? For that you could just use innerHTML on an element, like element.innerHTML = xml$s;

Comment: I suggest you load jQuery and do a `$.get(filename,function(data() { here data contains your html });`

Comment: @asgoth Yes, and although I'm not a huge fan of innerHTML, it looks like that's how JQuery handles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inject a HTML string into a DOM element, you could just use `innerHTML`:

```
element.innerHTML = xml$s;
```

But you probably want to [sanitize the HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side).