# Remove invalid html tags from a string

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way with javascript to remove invalid HTML tags from a string?

Ex: `<div> <foo></foo> </div>` should be transformed to `<div></div>`

Comment: If you search the balise you don't want and replace it with "" you will be find i guess

Comment: duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: I don't want to remove the entire HTML code, just remove the invalids tags. So it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to roll your own form of HTML sanitizer. I would not recommend that. Instead, check out other questions that have already asked for a sanitizer: [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)

Specifically, there's one available for use here: https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"><foo></foo></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML, 
    reg = /<foo>|<\/foo>/i;

str = str.replace(reg, " "); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```