# How to detect any non-html tags while parsing a html text

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, tags

In my extjs code, I am parsing through a html text part which I get from the database and present it on the UI. I had this issue while parsing through some text. There was a `<select>` in the html body which a user added to indicate something around that message. But while parsing the data, my extjs code treats that `<select>` as a html tag and was not able to process it. So the parsing stopped at that point and the remaining text is not getting displayed. That `<select>` has nothing to do with the html stuff, its just a normal plain text.

Can anyone please let me know how I can check for any non-HTML tags in the body content and ignore those tags.

Comment: `<select>` is an HTML tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove invalid html tags from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493125/remove-invalid-html-tags-from-a-string)