# Filter a html page so only certain tags are showing

Tags: javascript

I have the following html code

```
 <html>
 <body>
<div id='content'>
 <h1>afsdsdsdf</h1>
 <p>sdfsdfsdf</p>

 <h2>sfddfdf</h2>
```

```
 </body>
 </html>
```

How can I get it so it only outputs      `<h1>afsdsdsdf</h1>`
     `<h2>sfddfdf</h2>`
my code atm

```
var allhtml = ($('#content').html());
document.getElementById('JumpLinks').innerHTML = allhtml;
```

Comment: Do you have a HTML *document* or a *string* that contains that HTML?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/430240/1412255

Comment: you could add the css "p {display:none}" (just for this example that is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function textChange ( event )
{
    if ( event . keyCode !== 8 && event . keyCode !== 9 && event . keyCode !== 13 && ( event . keyCode < 32 || event . keyCode > 127 ) ) { return; }
    var newText = [];
    document . getElementById ( "input" ) . value . replace ( /<(\s*)?h([1-6])(\s+)([\s\w-=\"']*[^\s])?(\s*)?>(\s*)?([\s\w-=\"']*[^\s])(\s*)?<(\s*)?\/(\s*)?h([1-6])(\s*)?>/gi, function ( match, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, offset, string ) { newText . push ( "<h" + p2 + ( p4 . length === 0 ? "" : " " ) + p4 . toLowerCase () + ">" + p7 + "</h" + p11 + ">" ); } );
    // replace unnecesary whitespaces and case-insensitive tags: "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5" and "h6" and replace all text outside this tags
    // Example changes: "<hm>Fake</hm>Another text< H2 ABC='CBA' > Test 2 < / h2 > ... other ..." to: "<h2 abc='cba'>Test 2</h2>"
    // g - means global ( recursive ) search, i - means case-insensitive search
    document . getElementById ( "output" ) . value = newText . join ( "\n" );
}
```

RegExp explanation:

```
<                 <=> match the character: "<" literally
(\s+)             <=> match any whitespace one or more times
h                 <=> match the character: "h" literally
([1-6])           <=> match single characters from list: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" literally
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
([\s\w-=\"']*     <=> match string with: ( if ) any whitespace, ( if ) any alphanumeric characters and ( if ) any characters from list: "-", "=", """, "'" literally
[^\s])?           <=> previous string cannot end with one or more whitespaces
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
>                 <=> match the character: ">" literally
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
([\s\w-=\"']*     <=> match string with: ( if ) any whitespace, ( if ) any alphanumeric characters and ( if ) any characters from list: "-", "=", """, "'" literally
[^\s])            <=> previous string cannot end with one or more whitespaces
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
<                 <=> match the character: "<" literally
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
\/                <=> match the character "/" - this character is special in RegExp and you must precede this character by: "\"
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
h                 <=> match the character: "h" literally
([1-6])           <=> match single character from list: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" literally
(\s*)?            <=> match ( if ) any whitespace
>                 <=> match the character: ">" literally
```

My code does not correct syntax of the inserted code.
It only gets tags: "<h1>", "<h2>", "<h3>", "<h4>", "<h5>", "<h6>" and their contents. 
Example fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjDgN/1/)