# Extracting identifiers from a code snippet (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Problem: a snippet of code (typically a few lines) in language like Java, C++, etc. (not limiting it to particular language).

I need to extract words from it that seem like unique identifiers - variable names, function/method names, class names, etc.

Obviously that means skipping all the whitespace, newlines, brackets, punctuation, and importantly keywords.

I realize it's somewhat similar to this question: [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)

I guess some modification of that code using regexes could get me smth approximately good enough. But I wonder if there's a better (cleaner, shorter) way?

Comment: So, you need a parser that recognizes syntax for multiple languages? And you want to do it in a few lines of regular expressions? That's like trying to build an airplane using nothing but a blowtorch and a pair of paperclips

Comment: Emphatically, I do not need a parser. I need to extract identifiers that are not keywords.