# What is the standard approach for escaping harmful characters / sanitizing user's input with JS?

Tags: javascript

After reading tons of articles and StackOverflow responses I still don't get what is the industry standard approach for dealing with user's inputs (textarea and input type="text"). What and how should I escape chars? What and how should be stripped / replaced so JSON will not break, especially when the user can copy-paste some of the weirdest characters ever?

The doubtful solution that I have put in place a long time ago was:

```
String.prototype.escapeChars = function () {
 return this.replace(/\&/g, '&#x26;')
.replace(/\n\r?/g, '&#13;')
.replace(/\n/g, '&#13;')
.replace(/\r/g, '&#13;')
.replace(/\s/g, '&#32;')
.replace(/\</g, '&#x3c;')
.replace(/\"/g, '&#34;')
.replace(/\'/g, '&#39;')
.replace(/\>/g, '&#x3e;')
.replace(/\\/g, '&#x27;')
.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, '');
};
```

I would tremendously appreciate if someone will explain in detail or point to a good tutorial on how it should be done **PROPERLY** with vanilla js.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side check this one

Comment: There are little cases where front-end sanitizing makes sense. You should do it server-side, for the simple reason that you can't be sure the data you're receiving there ever met your script, nor that it ever came from a web-browser...

Comment: @Kaiido what are those cases where front-end sanitizing makes sense? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the industry standard approach for dealing with user's inputs

To use an appropriate library for the target data format.

> What and how should be stripped / replaced so JSON will not break, especially when the user can copy-paste some of the weirdest characters ever?

Nothing. Just use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and it will handle whatever is thrown at it.

For example, if you were sending data to a web service that expects JSON input:

```
const name = $('input[name=name]').val();
const address = $('input[name=address]').val();
const ajax = jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://example.com/endpoint",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ name, address })
});
ajax.then(data => console.log(data));
```

> The doubtful solution that I have put in place a long time ago was…

That looks like it is designed for converting to HTML, not JSON.

Comment: +1                                                                                               for "*appropriate for the target format*"

Comment: what would be an appropriate library examples?

Comment: As I said in the answer, JSON.stringify.

Comment: thank you. may I ask you another question? -> should js before sending data to server replace &, <,> and " ? or just leave it to the server-side?

Comment: I can't think of many situations where I'd want to, except maybe if I was working with a SOAP API … something I'd try to avoid doing if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is really that simple!