# Removing JavaScript from HTML inside an object

Tags: javascript, coverity

Full disclosure: I inherited the code. I was tasked to fix it. After 9 hours, I am turning to you, the hive mind.

Inside an object (`response`) is `response.Object` `Object` contains HTML code.

```
$("doodah").html(response.Object)
```

Coverity doesn't like this. It's vulnerable to a DOM XSS attack. Coverity is complaining about how it is vulnerable to an arbitrary JavaScript statement that can taint `respose.Object`.

So I tried to REGEX it out. No good. `.replace(RegEx_Clear_Scipt_Tags)` didn't work. I added RegEx to clear Script tags and in-line JavaScript. Coverity does not like this either.

Fine, so I tried a function that puts the code in a DIV, strips out the Script tags through DOM functions and returns the `innerHTML`

No good. Coverity didn't like that either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the source of `response`? Coverity isn't perfect, and sometimes you'll just have to ignore it from situation to situation.

Comment: ´reponse´ comes from an $.AJAX call. Specifically from.´success´. Coverity is not perfect and neither is the code. The code came from 2014 and no one has touched it until it was assigned to me.

Comment: This is how the backend was designed. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Forget about Coverity. Ship the code. There's nothing wrong with it unless the HTML input is from an untrusted source.

Comment: The only possible entrusted sources come from the search window. I looked at those and they are protected through the entire stack. Adding RegEx to the incoming HTML code? Should i still do that? And what do i do about this Stack Overflow entry?

Comment: I guess you can leave it there and if you find another solution post it. Or maybe someone else has some brilliant idea.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to sanitize user-provided HTML within the client.  Have you looked at the question [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side/430240#430240)?

Comment: Would it solve anything on the Coverity side?

Comment: @JR.sc I don't know whether it would out of the box, but Coverity can be configured to understand new sanitizer functions, so there is a path to a solution there.  In any case, I'd focus on making the app secure (which, if I understand correctly, it is not) before worrying about making Coverity happy.

Comment: Almost every other issue i resolved except for SQL un/pw which is forced on the SQL side making it a non-issue and this stick!in-the-mud which i guess doesnt have a solution at the moment.